# Htaccess redirect doesnt work on my wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I am struggling with a redirect problem. I am not familiar with this and I tried for more than a week to resolve it but I couldn't find an answer, despite a lot of Google searching.

Let me explain: 
A customer just asked me to create 3 new websites, with the content of the original one (he wanted to split the original website into three new ones).
All of them use WordPress.

Now that the three domains are all ready, I have to redirect all pages of the original site to the new website page using `.htaccess`.

#### Example:

On the original site I have a custom post type named "FAQ" which the URL looks like this:

```
https://old-site.fr/?faqs=name-of-my-question/
```

and I want it to redirect to:

```
https://faq.new-site.com/name-of-my-question/
```

I tried with 301 redirects but nothing worked.

Here's the last syntax I tried:

```
Redirect 301 ^/?faqs=name-of-my-question https://faq.new-site.com/name-of-my-question
```

Here is the full .htaccess code :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Redirect 301 ^/index.php?faqs=name-of-my-question https://faq.new-site.com/name-of-my-question

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Still nothing... How do i check if mod_rewrite is enabled ?

Nothing works... and I need help!

Comment: check `mod_rewrite` is enable or not?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
Redirect 301 ^/index.php?faqs=name-of-my-question https://faq.new-site.com/name-of-my-question
```

Or just try the complete url to just debug if is a `mod_rewrite` issue eg.

```
Redirect 301 https://old-site.fr/?faqs=name-of-my-question/ https://faq.new-site.com/name-of-my-question
```

Also check if `RewriteEngine On` and the rule is after or before the WordPress generated rules.

Comment: Neither of these examples will work. The mod_alias `Redirect` directive uses simple prefix matching (it does not use a regex) to match against the URL-path only. The URL-path does not include the query string or the scheme+hostname. So these directives cannot possibly match the requested URL.You need to use mod_rewrite to perform these kinds of redirects. Since the OP is using WordPress then you should be using mod_rewrite for everything anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> Here's the last syntax I tried:
>
> ```
> Redirect 301 ^/?faqs=name-of-my-question https://faq.new-site.com/name-of-my-question
> ```

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive does not match the query string, so this will never match. And the second argument is not a regex, so `^/?` is invalid.

To match the query string, you need to use mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule` and `RewriteCond` directives). Since you are using WordPress, which has it's own mod_rewrite directives, then you must also use mod_rewrite. (It is not advisable to mix redirects from both mod_alias and mod_rewrite as you can get unexpected conflicts.)

Any redirect you add to `.htaccess` must go before the existing WordPress directives. ie. Before the `# BEGIN WordPress` section.

Try something like the following instead:

```
# REDIRECT: https://old-site.fr/?faqs=name-of-my-question/
#       TO: https://faq.new-site.com/name-of-my-question/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-site\.fr [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^faqs=name-of-my-question/
RewriteRule ^$ https://faq.new-site.com/name-of-my-question/ [R=302,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
:
```

If `name-of-my-question` is simply a placeholder for *any* question then you can do a more generalised *any question* like the following:

```
# REDIRECT: https://old-site.fr/?faqs=<any-question>/
#       TO: https://faq.new-site.com/<any-question>/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-site\.fr [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^faqs=([a-z-]+)/
RewriteRule ^$ https://faq.new-site.com/%1/ [R=302,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
:
```

If `old-site.fr` and `new-site.com` reside on different servers then you can remove the initial condition that checks against the `HTTP_HOST`.

The `%1` backreference in the second `RewriteRule` *substitution* captures the `<name-of-my-question>` from the query string.

Note that these are a 302 (temporary) redirects. Only change it to 301 (permanent) once you have tested that it works OK (to avoid caching problems) - if indeed it is intended to be *permanent*.

---

**UPDATE:**

> ... it didn't work.

Try changing the `RewriteRule` *pattern* from `^$` to `^(index\.php)?$`. In other words:

```
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ https://faq.new-site.com/name-of-my-question/ [R=302,L]
```

Comment: well, I have been working on other bugs and come back to test your solution but, it didn't work. I tried both example but nothing work.

There is a redirection plugin on the original website, I deactivated it hoping it would solve everything but it didn't either... I am out of ideas...

Comment: "it didn't work" - nothing happened at all? So, `https://old-site.fr/?faqs=name-of-my-question/` just displayed the old page as usual? Presumably you don't have custom permalinks enabled at your old site? Are your old and new sites physically different servers? You can try changing the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ to read `^(index\.php)?$` (I'll update my answer). Any WP plugins will execute much later, so that isn't the problem.